# Python logging external library messages to file

Tags: python-3.x, logging, error-logging

I have a `myapp.py` that looks like:

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

fh = logging.FileHandler('out.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(fh)


import ext_library
logger.info('Starting...')
ext_library.do_something()
```

`.do_something()` outputs a bunch of INFO messages from different modules/functions of `ext_library`. It looks like:

```
[INFO 05-10 19:40:59] ext_library.model.utils: Some information here.
[INFO 05-10 19:40:59] ext_library.service: Started to run inner function.
[INFO 05-10 19:40:59] ext_library.service: Finishing...
```

All of `ext_library` has loggers following the `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` format. I would like **everything** to be logged to `out.log`. What I'm finding is that:

- `Starting...` and all the INFO messages coming from `ext_library` are displayed on the terminal.
- **None** of the INFO messages from `ext_library` are getting logged to `out.log`.

What am I doing wrong? I also find that even if I change the log level of `logger` to `logging.ERROR`, all the INFO messages from `ext_library` are still appearing on the terminal which is not what I expected... am I not propagating the `setLevel` and `addHandler` correctly?

Thanks.